# MVC VB.NET: Trying to reference a radiobutton value by passing it as byval param in action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

RB:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="accountShow()"  runat="server" name="GuestAccount" class="GuestAccount" value="1" />


<input type="radio" onclick="accountShow()"  runat="server" name="GuestAccount" class="GuestAccount" value="0" />
```

Action:

```
Public Function Edit(ByVal guestAccount As String) As ActionResult
```

However I am receiving a null value

Comment: <input type="radio" onclick="accountShow()"  runat="server" name="GuestAccountRB" class="GuestAccount" value="1" /> &nbsp;Account&nbsp;
                              <input type="radio" onclick="guestHide()"  runat="server" name="GuestAccountRB" class="GuestAccount" value="0" />&nbsp;Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be declaring server controls there; remove the `runat="server"` and I think it should work. Making them ASP.NET server controls means that the actual name/id will be something different, so MVC won't find it.

Generally, you don't use server controls in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MVC helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx) to render your radiobutton controls in your view which should fix your issue:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("GuestAccount", "0", new { @class = "GuestAccount", onclick = "AccountShow()" }) %>
<%=Html.RadioButton("GuestAccount", "1", new { @class = "GuestAccount", onclick = "AccountShow()" }) %>
```